# How to looping variable value in query insert

Tags: php, mysql, loops, sql-insert

I have koneksi_class with code.

How to looping $value in query INSERT INTO $table VALUES ($value0, $value1, $value2)

```
<?php 
  function tambahAnggota($value0, $value1, $value2, $value3, $value4, $value5) {
      $table = $_GET['tujuan'];
      $query = "INSERT INTO $table VALUES ('$value0', '$value1','$value2')";
        $hasil = mysql_query($query);
        if ($hasil)
            echo"<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=?tujuan=$table'>";
        else
           echo "Pesan error: ".mysql_error();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> [`func_get_args`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) — Returns an array comprising a function's argument list
>
> [`func_num_args`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) — Returns the number of arguments passed to the function

Using this methods, you can achieve looping all the arguments like this:

```
<?php
function tambahAnggota($value0, $value1, $value2, $value3, $value4, $value5)
{
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    $values = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {

        array_push($values, '\''.func_get_arg($i).'\'');
    }
    $strValues = implode(',', $values);
    $table = $_GET['tujuan'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO $table VALUES ($strValues)";
    $hasil = mysql_query($query);
    if ($hasil)
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=?tujuan=$table'>";
    else
        echo "Pesan error: " . mysql_error();
}

tambahAnggota(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

Comment: I get a notif Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'tambahAnggota' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) , what should I do?

Comment: `tambahAnggota(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);` is just for demonstration purpose. You should remove it while applying in your code. Just take function..